# Unable to reduce the checkpointing time by "storage.tsdb.max-block-duration

Tags: prometheus, kube-prometheus-stack

I am using the "prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack" --version 47.1.0

I am getting OOM so I wish to reduce the memory footprint by triggering the checkpointing early.
In order to do so, I passed the following in prometheus

prometheusSpec
additionalArgs:

- name: storage.tsdb.max-block-duration
  value: 10m

According to my knowledge, this should set the chunkrange as 10m. So the checkpointing should trigger every 10 * 3 /2 = 15mins
But I don't see that happening.

What am I missing?